# Android InApp billing purchase from another activity

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to perform InApp Purchase calling a method in my first activity from my second activity (JsInterface).

On my first activity (MainActivity), i have the following code (partial) :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
    CancelNotification(getApplicationContext(),1);
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = MY_KEY;
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);        
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
         public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
               if (!result.isSuccess()) { Log.d("IAB", "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result); } 
               else { 
                   Log.d("IAB", "In-app Billing is set up OK");           
                   purchaseItem("android.test.purchased");
               }
         }
    });     
    chargement();                
}

public void purchaseItem(String sku_item) {
    final String sku = sku_item;
    Log.e("PURCHASE","Accessing method");
    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase){
            Log.e("PURCHASE","Accessing method result");
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e("PURCHASE","Error : "+ sku);
                return;
            }      
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(sku)) {
                Log.e("PURCHASE","OK : " + sku);
            }               
        }
    };
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, MY_TOKEN);
}   

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {     
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
}
```

Everything is ok on this side : IabSetup is ok, and the first purchaseItem() is correctly called and executed.

Now i have a second activity which is a JsInterface that calls purchaseItem() method in MainActivity :

```
public class jsinterface {
Context mContext;
jsinterface(Context c) { mContext = c; }        
@JavascriptInterface
public void purchaseSku(String sku) {        
    Log.e("JSInterface","Purchase SKU : " + sku);        
    MainActivity cls2= new MainActivity();
    cls2.purchaseItem(sku);
}
```

}

The result is that my MainActivity's purchaseItem() method is correctly called but launchPurchaseFlow() or IabPurchaseFinishedListener is not.

Any idea why PurchaseFlow is called from MainActivity but not from the second activity ?

Comment: You're not supposed to create instances of Acitivities on you're own, as you're doing with the line `MainActivity cls2 = new MainActivity()` because the methods such as `onCreate()` and any others are never called by the OS. So when you try to use `mHelper` in your method, it hasn't been initialized because onCreate was never called. I don't have a solution for this, but that's the issue you're encountering. You'll have to figure out another way without creating an instance of MainActivity of your own

Comment: I agree, the problem surely comes from something missing about the mHelper initialization, and i'm looking for the way to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Use this library for easy inapp integration:

https://github.com/serso/android-checkout/blob/master/README.md

Do it as the readme tells you. Create a class that extends Application and initialize the library there.

Now you can easily launch a purchase from every activity in your app, by calling some functions.